# Debugging Antlr grammar code (language = 'CSharp3') with ANTLRWorks

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, antlr, antlrworks

Using ANTLRWorks, I'm trying to use debugging feature.

Following the instructions in [this page](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=557075), I could generate the cs code, but I have this error message.

[image]

I made that java/javaw can communicate through firewall.

[image]

What might be wrong?

Comment: Your ANTLR implementing is in C#3, or you are trying to parse a C#3 file and want to debug your C#3 grammar?

Comment: @Ira : My ANTLR target is C#3. I don't need to debug C#3 grammar.

Comment: @prosseek, what happens if your shut down the firewall entirely?

Comment: @Bart : The same result without the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I managed to solve it by adding the path to JDK (javac, javaw, java) to the PATH variable. It turned out that indicating the path to the compiler in ANTLRWorks settings is ok for code generation but not for debugging.